# Blender removes images with fake user

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting

It happened again, and im confused why is that happening.

Blender version: `4.0.2`

##### I put fake user (shield icon) on every image I texture paint to prevent this, but it just does not stop....

I come back to project and every image is black.

Mostly I paint masks to do procedural shading, but sometimes I paint colors and mix them. But that does not matter. All images were of size 2048. One image was size 3000.

[image: Blender preview]

That group nodes are just for mixing layers and organization.

Are images stored in blend1 file? or share across incremental file saves? I checked few other and they are also black.

I don't save in texture panel with button "save all", is that the cause? Usually all textures are in place.

I did not check "fake user" for main material which used images.

[image: texure paint window]

###### If some other details could be helpfull, ask in comments and I will update question.

Comment: I believe that Blender will only automatically save edited texture files within the Blend file if you have the File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources option checked when you save your Blend file. That's why tutorials usually tell you to be sure to save your image files.

Comment: The fake user only prevents datablocks from being deleted when they are not used. It is not intended to automatically save changes on images. It only means the image datablock will be saved, so Blender still "knows" there is an image even if it is not used in a texture node for example.

Comment: @JohnEason oh I did reset my blender recently, I will enable packing now, it was off

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I do save them, and they dissapear, even with automatick packing as John said :(

Comment: Actually I don't know if automatic packing helps. Bur if you really physically save them on disk (after painting on them, not before), then the image file should have everyrhing.

Comment: It looks like I must click "Save all images" and then save file. I can actually replicate this bug. If I do "Save" File, then images are not save and stay black or(previously saved), but if I do save all images and save it works. Also if I do "save" only, blender asks for saving pictures, but it does not save them... that was misleading

Comment: As mentioned earlier, make sure to save your image files - image files, not blend files.